# How could I update a global collection with a async method and binding in the view?

Tags: wpf, async-await, model-binding

I am rtying to get some data from database to get the needed items for some comboBoxes. I have an async method that get all the data and it is called from the construtor. The code is this.

```
private async Task getDataASync()
{
    Task<List<Typ01>> miTsk01 = VariablesGlobales.getData01Async();
    Task<List<Type02>> miTsk02 = VariablesGlobales.getData02Async();
    Task<List<Type03>> miTskT03 = VariablesGlobales.getData03Async();
    Task<List<Type04>> miTsk04 = VariablesGlobales.getData04Async();



    await Task.WhenAll(miTsk01,
    miTsk02,
    miTsk03,
    miTsk04).ConfigureAwait(false);


    GlobalVariables.vgData01.AddRange(miTsk01.Result);
    GlobalVariables.vgData02.AddRange(miTsk02.Result);
    GlobalVariables.vgData03.AddRange(miTsk03.Result);
    GlobalVariables.vgData04.AddRange(miTsk04.Result);
}




public MyViewModel()
{
    getDataASync();
}
```

XAML

```
    <ComboBox
      SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem01}"
      ItemsSource="{x:Static vg:VariablesGlobales.vgData01}">
    </ComboBox>

<ComboBox
  SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem02}"
  ItemsSource="{x:Static vg:VariablesGlobales.vgData02}">
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox
  SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem03}"
  ItemsSource="{x:Static vg:VariablesGlobales.vgData03}">
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox
  SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem04}"
  ItemsSource="{x:Static vg:VariablesGlobales.vgData04}">
</ComboBox>
```

The problem is that I get an error that says the collectionView can't be modified by another subprocess diferent than Dispatcher.

I have tried to create a property in my view model that get the data from the global variable and the view binds this property and then it works.

Really I don't understand very good the problem, because in the method that get the data from database, it waits until I get all the data and later I update the global collections. I thought that I was in the same thread than the main application, but it seems that I am wrong.

How could I update the global collections to can be binded by the view?

Thanks.

Comment: *Don't* use `ConfigureAwait(false)` if you want to work on the UI thread

Comment: Don't use static collections either, this violates both the MVVM pattern, the way data binding is supposed to work and good design rules in general. Use a *ViewModel properties* to store that collection and bind the `ItemSource` to them just like any other property, eg `MySelectedItem04`. When each collection property is modified, raise the appropriate `PropertyChanged` event. If you don't want to update the UI for each assignment, delay raising the events until the end of `getDataAsync`

Comment: Perhaps a *better* option would be to construct the ViewModel from the results of `getDataASync` and any other similar services and bind the completed ViewModel to the View's context in a single operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle this.

The simplest is just to use ConfigureAwait(true) which ensures that any continuation will be on the same thread.

```
await Task.WhenAll(miTsk01,
miTsk02,
miTsk03,
miTsk04).ConfigureAwait(true);

GlobalVariables.vgData01.AddRange( await miTsk01);
GlobalVariables.vgData02.AddRange( await miTsk02);
GlobalVariables.vgData03.AddRange( await miTsk03);
GlobalVariables.vgData04.AddRange( await miTsk04);
```

A couple of notes

- You should avoid using Task.Result as this can cause a deadlock, even though the Task is supposed to be completed already - just use await task instead (as above).
- Your collections should probably be ObservableCollection rather than List, which will reflect any changes to the List to the bound UI controls. These don't support AddRange() as standard so you will need to add the items individually.

The alternative method is to use a class such as [this one](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform%20(NET45)/Threading/DispatcherHelper.cs) from MvvmLight, which will capture the UI context at application startup which can then be used as the context for UI updates from a different thread.

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(true)` is the default, and thus not needed at all.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That is correct, but I prefer to be explicit - especially in this case when the required behaviour is different from the common usage.

Comment: The common usage is to *not* use `ConfigureAwait()` at all, thus returning to the original execution context. Instead of making anything explicit, it adds confusion. BTW those `await Result` calls won't even compile. The OP used the correct calls with `miTsk01.Result` etc.

Comment: The OP used the correct calls with miTsk01.Result etc. Using `await` to await an already completed task creates unnecessary state machine steps

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: An article that says the exact opposite of this answer. It doesn't say anything about *completed* tasks. That *is* mentioned in Stephen Cleary's book and articles

Answer (score 1):

> Really I don't understand very good the problem, because in the method that get the data from database, it waits until I get all the data and later I update the global collections. I thought that I was in the same thread than the main application, but it seems that I am wrong.

Provided that you call the `getDataASync()` on the UI thread, the only thing you have to do is to capture the context by removing the call to `ConfigureAwait(false)`:

```
await Task.WhenAll(miTsk01,
    miTsk02,
    miTsk03,
    miTsk04);
```

`ConfigureAwait(false)` prevents the context from being captured which means that the remainder of your `getDataASync()` will be executed on a thread pool thread once the `Task.WhenAll` method has completed, as opposed to being executed on the same thread that the `getDataASync()` method was originally called on.

It's considered as best practice to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in service methods and anywhere you can basically, but methods that does require a context, such as `getDataASync()` where you populate data-bound collections, is clearly an exception. Please refer to [@Stephen Cleary's MSDN Magazine article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for more information about this.